# HIve: Table creation failing with "Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE"

Tags: hive, hiveql

I've a `Table_1` with a following structure:

```
ID  ABR CTG DATERNG               VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 IND
001 BVF NJ  06/01/2019-07/30/2019 9.4  7.8  8.9   Y
002 BHT JP  05/01/2018-05/08/2019 89.5 55.4 67.4  N
003 GHT JK  09/09/2017-03/03/2018 45.4 45.3 0.0   N
..
```

Trying another `Table_2` from `Table_1`

Wrote the below simple piece of hive query:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_2
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
AS SELECT * FROM Table_1;
```

But getting the below `error` message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive 
Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{},"value": 
{"_col0":001,"_col1":"BVF","_col2":"NJ","_col3":"06/01/2019- 
07/30/2019","_col4":"9.4","_col5":7.8,"_col6":8.9,"_col7":"Y"}}

Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 
killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1558653107192_0189_1_01 [Reducer 2] 
killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to 
VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
```

Any help/ suggestion to resolve the issue. As I am not getting what's wrong in the query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you once try with below syntax.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE Table_2 stored as parquet
      AS SELECT * FROM Table_1;
```

**(or)**

**`By using ROW FORMAT SERDE:`**

```
CREATE TABLE Table_2
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat' 
as SELECT * FROM Table_1;
```

AFAIK delimiter doesn't have any effect on parquet format, and hive internally manages the delimiter in case of non text format tables.

**In case if you need to have delimiters also included:**

**`Then create table_2:`**

```
CREATE TABLE Table_2(col1 int) --specify column names
ROW FORMAT delimited
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat';
```

Then run insert statement to load data from table_1 to table_2

```
insert into Table_2 select * from Table_1;
```